# Time inserted through query showing up with more numbers after minutes

Tags: html, sql

I'm inserting a time field onto a table in which the time field has a length of 6 in the database.

I'm using Tempos Dominus Bootstrap library for the time inside the form

### HTML Form

```html
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="time">Hora</label>
                        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker3" data-target-input="nearest">
                            <input type="text" name="time" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker3"/>
                            <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker3" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                                <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

### SQL Query

```js
$time = strtotime($_POST['time']);
    $time = date('HH:mm', $time);


    //insere novo turno na base de dados
    $sql = "INSERT INTO shifts (name, origin, destination, transport_number, status, date, time) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../shifts.php?error=sqlerror");
        exit();
    } else {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $username, $origin, $destination, $transport, $status, $date, $time);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        header("Location: ../shifts.php?newrecord=success");
        exit();

    }
```

I tried using the H:i:s format but it didn't seem to work.

### Expected Result

11:07:00

### Actual Result

11:07:00.000000

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show is your expected result and your actual result.

Comment: What is the type of column in the database? Seems like that's where the issue is, not with your code.

Comment: TIME (6) is the type of the column with the length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of your column is TIME(6). As mentioned for example [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-time/),

> TIME(N) is a column where N is an integer that represents the
>   fractional part [of a second], which is up to 6 digits.

Or in other words, TIME(6) means six zeros after the dot. I believe to get your result your column should have TIME(0), or just TIME, as a datatype, or you will have to cut off the zeroes.